# Google Maps API: JSON response for location with non-English name

Tags: python, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

While parsing

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Inha+Technical+College
```

I get

```
"ZERO_RESULTS"
```

But if I use "인하공업전문대학" (Korean name of this institution) instead of "Inha Technical College"

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=인하공업전문대학
```

everything works just fine.

At the same time, if I search for "Inha Technical College" in Google Maps manually it shows its exact location and Korean name.

I have a whole database of Korean institutions with English names only, is there a way to retrieve JSON data using English names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you search based on names  (not addresses) of locations request the places-API

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Inha+Technical+College&key=[InsertYourKeyHere]
```

result:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "253 Yonghyeon-dong, Nam-gu, Incheon, South Korea",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4480158,
               "lng" : 126.6575041
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/school-71.png",
         "id" : "819a851ed99429ddf73b0e8b0cb4cc64c7652a99",
         "name" : "인하공업전문대학",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 2448,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105692088629861058406/photos\"\u003e박용수\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CoQBcwAAAFgRIWsD_gjcC-0IMtsaxyChMnj0m-NpNzqSrKlQOj36Wwo22KtJUseCxo2HZqdS3J2iRqVQrgUvZ9xUUkrK8WRuDIfcSh2-Tg7fqTPjL6D9AXrjr0rDy6AC15LbSZ3xrcSnVvP3OcYt4pP-gDIPHJ3KGoYFJC9imhzQj_HhQs_XEhDLaY1ReKU_r1r0TRbxkV_aGhTVldlttalRdf40aHg08HZ2NK9fFw",
               "width" : 3264
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJiRCw26t5ezURzCfeytfvQ0Q",
         "rating" : 4.6,
         "reference" : "CnRrAAAAy19YXkr7RrlHwjGkiYApVfE1EsQvgiPcnTs6GlK-4BCZdYyM29mDdoD8gCtZ87dijqjO5G6yeOQCECK_5-_N4hedqVak3fPquVBMx1IpmvkwcWJ3O2Jezo68wj53GC1XSPUwAp2c_Zmrv4Ez9CIRSxIQjtmXbKBBxwtsXhE7RjbgbhoUSeitgEgzLDWY39SxgVN-DK5wsd0",
         "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Note: the places-webservice requires a API-key

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dr.Molle!